# iOS Simulator in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I think that in my storyboard file in xcode that it has me using an iPhone 5 display, but when i load the simulator, i think it is an iPhone 4 display. So the view doesn't look the same. Does anyone know how to use an iPhone 5 display as my Simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the iOS simulator menu

Hardware -> Device -> iPhone (Retina 4-inch)

**EDIT**
The device looks like this

[image]

Comment: Ya but then it doesn't put the iPhone device as the simulator.. its a zoomed in screen of the iPhone 5... I want the iPhone device visible as the iPhone 5.. @GabrielePetronella

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the device. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you cannot see the device properly, probably the resolution it's too high and you need to scale it down from `Window -> Scale`

Comment: i tried scaling it.. but for some reason it still pops up in a window of some sort.. it says iOS Simulator - iPhone (Retina 4-inch). I want it to look like the pic you put up ^ but it won't... @GabrielePetronella

Comment: When it is scaled, it hides the bezel and it's shown in a plain windows. That's normal and I guess the only thing you can do is to increase your screen resolution (or buy a MBP retina :P)

Comment: There is a weird feature that for some scaling settings only the actual window is displayed, not the frame and "the button".  Yet another annoying "feature" of Xcode.

Comment: I don't actually know the reason, still consider that you can "press" the home button using the shortcut `Command+Shift+H`

Comment: So there is no way that I can fix this? @HotLicks

Comment: So there is no way that I can fix this? @GabrielePetronella

Comment: I figure I can live with it.  The simulator is far from perfect.

Comment: @trludt nope, unfortunately that's the way it is. No full resolution, no bezels.

Comment: Ya I've been looking everywhere for solutions for this. but your right.. no solution i guess.. Hopefully they come out with one soon! Thanks again though! @GabrielePetronella

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are right. For some reason they just don't have the actual visual presentation of the iPhone 5 in the simulator yet.. Hopefully they will soon though! that would be cool!